# Bitwise AND operation not clear

Tags: c, gcc, bitwise-operators, bit, bitwise-and

I'm trying to understand the bitwise AND operator  in C; it works until I put a 0 in front of 177.

I'm doing this by hand to make sure I understand what the compiler is doing

```
#include <stdio.h>

main () {
    printf ("%d\n", 1999 & 177); 
    return 0; 
}
```

The answer above is 129, this is my answer when I do it by hand as well

```
#include <stdio.h>

main () {
   printf ("%d\n", 1999 & 0177); 
   return 0; 
}
```

The compiler above gives me the answer 79, can someone please explain how it gets to the answer 79?

Comment: 0177 is an [octal literal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal).

Comment: A prefix of 0 on a number usually indicates that the number is in base-8. 0117 != 117

Comment: Many duplicates:(

Comment: Sorry didn't think of that, did try to research my question before hand

Answer (score 3):

177 is base 10 (decimal) = 0xB1 = 0261<sub>8</sub>.

0177 is base 8 (octal) = 127<sub>10</sub> or 0x7F.

0x177 is base 16 (hexadecimal) = 375<sub>10</sub> or 0567<sub>8</sub>.

```
1999 = 0x07CF = 0000 0111 1100 1111 Binary.
0177 = 0x007F = 0000 0000 0111 1111
              & -------------------
                0000 0000 0100 1111 = 79
```